# Memory game using Python and PyGame

Tags: python, beginner, game, python-3.x, pygame

I am a beginner in Python and PyGame and wrote a memory game. I think there are lot of things I could have done better. I am looking for some advice on how I can improve the design and refactoring of the code.

```
# the imports
import pygame
import random
from itertools import product
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.color import Color


# the constants
FPS = 30
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 400
SQUARE_SIZE = 50
SQUARE_GAP = 10
BOARD_WIDTH = 8
BOARD_HEIGHT = 4
X_MARGIN = (SCREEN_WIDTH - (BOARD_WIDTH * (SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_GAP))) // 2
Y_MARGIN = (SCREEN_HEIGHT - (BOARD_HEIGHT * (SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_GAP))) // 2

# the board size must be even due to pairs
assert (BOARD_HEIGHT * BOARD_WIDTH) % 2 == 0, 'The board size must be even'

# the shapes
DIAMOND = 'diamond'
SQUARE = 'square'
TRIANGLE = 'triangle'
CIRCLE = 'circle'

BGCOLOR = Color('blue')

# the main function
def main():
    global screen, clock

    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Memory game')

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    shape = (DIAMOND, SQUARE, TRIANGLE, CIRCLE)
    colors = (Color('cyan'), Color('magenta'), Color('gray'), Color('chocolate'))

    # There should be enough symbols
    assert len(shape) * len(colors) >= BOARD_HEIGHT * BOARD_WIDTH // 2, 'There are not sufficient icons'

    board = get_random_board(shape, colors)
    revealed = [[False] * BOARD_WIDTH for i in range(BOARD_HEIGHT)]  # keeps track of visibility of square

    mouse_x = None
    mouse_y = None
    mouse_clicked = False
    first_selection = None

    running = True
    start_game_animation(board)

    while running:
        screen.fill(BGCOLOR)
        draw_board(board, revealed)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                running = False
            elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                mouse_clicked = True

        x, y = get_pos(mouse_x, mouse_y)

        if x is not None and y is not None:
            if not revealed[x][y]:
                if mouse_clicked:
                    revealed[x][y] = True
                    draw_square(board, revealed, x, y)

                    if first_selection is None:
                        first_selection = (x, y)
                    else:
                        pygame.time.wait(1000)
                        if board[x][y] != board[first_selection[0]][first_selection[1]]:
                            revealed[x][y] = False
                            revealed[first_selection[0]][first_selection[1]] = False
                        first_selection = None

                    if game_won(revealed):

                        game_won_animation(board, revealed)

                        board = get_random_board(shape, colors)
                        revealed = [[False] * BOARD_WIDTH for i in range(BOARD_HEIGHT)]
                        start_game_animation(board)

                else:
                    draw_select_box(x, y)

        mouse_clicked = False
        pygame.display.update()


def game_won(revealed):
    """ Returns whether all squares are found"""

    return all(all(x) for x in revealed)


def game_won_animation(board, revealed):
    """ Flashes background colors when the game is won"""

    color1 = Color('cyan')
    color2 = BGCOLOR
    for i in range(10):
        color1, color2 = color2, color1
        screen.fill(color1)
        draw_board(board, revealed)
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.wait(300)


def start_game_animation(board):
    """Starts game by randomly showing 5 squares"""

    coordinates = list(product(range(BOARD_HEIGHT), range(BOARD_WIDTH)))
    random.shuffle(coordinates)

    revealed = [[False] * BOARD_WIDTH for i in range(BOARD_HEIGHT)]

    screen.fill(BGCOLOR)
    draw_board(board, revealed)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.wait(500)

    for sz in range(0, BOARD_HEIGHT * BOARD_WIDTH, 5):
        l = coordinates[sz: sz + 5]
        for x in l:
            revealed[x[0]][x[1]] = True
            draw_square(board, revealed, *x)
        pygame.time.wait(500)
        for x in l:
            revealed[x[0]][x[1]] = False
            draw_square(board, revealed, *x)


def get_random_board(shape, colors):
    """ Generates the board by random shuffling"""

    icons = list(product(shape, colors))
    num_icons = BOARD_HEIGHT * BOARD_WIDTH // 2
    icons = icons[:num_icons] * 2

    random.shuffle(icons)
    board = [icons[i:i + BOARD_WIDTH]
             for i in range(0, BOARD_HEIGHT * BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_WIDTH)]
    return board


def get_coord(x, y):
    """ Gets the coordinates of particular square.
        The squares are number height wise and then width wise.
        So the x and y are interchanged."""

    top = X_MARGIN + y * (SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_GAP)
    left = Y_MARGIN + x * (SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_GAP)
    return top, left


def draw_icon(icon, x, y):
    """Draws the icon of (x, y) square"""

    px, py = get_coord(x, y)
    if icon[0] == DIAMOND:
        pygame.draw.polygon(screen, icon[1],
                            ((px + SQUARE_SIZE // 2, py + 5), (px + SQUARE_SIZE - 5, py + SQUARE_SIZE // 2),
                             (px + SQUARE_SIZE // 2, py + SQUARE_SIZE - 5), (px + 5, py + SQUARE_SIZE // 2)))
    elif icon[0] == SQUARE:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, icon[1],
                         (px + 5, py + 5, SQUARE_SIZE - 10, SQUARE_SIZE - 10))
    elif icon[0] == TRIANGLE:
        pygame.draw.polygon(screen, icon[1],
                            ((px + SQUARE_SIZE // 2, py + 5), (px + 5, py + SQUARE_SIZE - 5),
                             (px + SQUARE_SIZE - 5, py + SQUARE_SIZE - 5)))
    elif icon[0] == CIRCLE:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, icon[1],
                           (px + SQUARE_SIZE // 2, py + SQUARE_SIZE // 2), SQUARE_SIZE // 2 - 5)


def get_pos(cx, cy):
    """Gets the square (x, y) position  from the cartesian coordinates.
       The squares are number height wise and then width wise.
       So the cx and cy are interchanged."""

    if cx < X_MARGIN or cy < Y_MARGIN:
        return None, None

    x = (cy - Y_MARGIN) // (SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_GAP)
    y = (cx - X_MARGIN) // (SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_GAP)

    if x >= BOARD_HEIGHT or y >= BOARD_WIDTH or (cx - X_MARGIN) % (SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_GAP) > SQUARE_SIZE or (cy - Y_MARGIN) % (SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_GAP) > SQUARE_SIZE:
        return None, None
    else:
        return x, y


def draw_square(board, revealed, x, y):
    """Draws a particular square"""

    coords = get_coord(x, y)
    square_rect = (*coords, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BGCOLOR, square_rect)
    if revealed[x][y]:
        draw_icon(board[x][y], x, y)
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Color('gold'), square_rect)
    pygame.display.update(square_rect)


def draw_board(board, revealed):
    """Draws the entire board"""

    for x in range(BOARD_HEIGHT):
        for y in range(BOARD_WIDTH):
            draw_square(board, revealed, x, y)


def draw_select_box(x, y):
    """Draws the highlight box around the square"""

    px, py = get_coord(x, y)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, Color('red'), (px - 5, py - 5, SQUARE_SIZE + 10, SQUARE_SIZE + 10), 5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

From [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide:

> Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools. There is one defensible use case for a wildcard import, which is to republish an internal interface as part of a public API (for example, overwriting a pure Python implementation of an interface with the definitions from an optional accelerator module and exactly which definitions will be overwritten isn't known in advance).

You aren't using magic values.  Yipperdeoble!  You define constants at the beginning of the file, instead.  That's just great!

I spy with my little eye some global variables.  Global variables are almost never needed.  Whenever you want to use a global variable, you should ask yourself how many functions use this variable.  If it is just one function (or at module-level) and a function it calls, you should be using arguments to the function and return values.  If it matters to many functions, those functions are probably closely-enough related that they should be put within a class.  The global variable should then be converted to an instance attribute.  In this case, I would use a class.

I see that you use list comprehensions when you create a list with many of the same sublists.  That's terrific!  If you were to use list multiplication instead, you would just have so many references *to the same list*.  I would suggest one small thing, though.  It is common practice to use an underscore (`_`) as the name for a variable that is not used (such as in `[False] * BOARD_WIDTH for i in ...`).  That makes it more clear to future readers that it is unused.

You use `is` and `is not` when comparing to `None`.  Many people don't do that, but it is indeed recommended by PEP 8.  Keep up the good work!

I see that you are familiar with `all()` and generator expressions.  Your `game_won()` function is to be admired.  That is the most efficient way.

Your `start_game_animation()` function converts `product(...)` to a list.  That is unnecessary.  Instead, use another `itertools` function for the slicing:

```
from itertools import product, islice

...

def start_game_animation(board):
    coordinates = product(...)
    ...
    for l in islice(coordinates, 0, BOARD_HEIGHT * BOARD_WIDTH, 5):
        ...
```

That is more efficient because you aren't storing all of that information in memory.  While we are dealing with that code, `l` isn't a very descriptive name.  It is also so similar to `1` that you are apt to confuse future readers.  (It is even mentioned specifically in PEP 8 not to use `l`, `O` or `I` as variable names because of the digits that they look like in some fonts).

Your `get_random_board()` function could be improved (in efficiency) by using multiple functions from `itertools`:

```
icons = product(shape, colors)
num_icons = BOARD_HEIGHT * BOARD_WIDTH // 2
icons = list(islice(icons, None, num_icons)) * 2
random.shuffle(icons)

return [icons[i: i + BOARD_WIDTH]
        for i in range(0, BOARD_HEIGHT * BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_WIDTH)]
```

There is more that could be done that doesn't involve lists at all, but considering the size of the board, it would only barely affect the performance and is a little hard to understand.

Your `draw_icon()` function has many very long lines.  I would suggest splitting them up a little bit.  You could even define variables that would make it more clear what different parts of the equation are.  You also figure out `icon[0]` once for each shape.  Instead, define a variable and use it.  You also don't account for the times when the shape is not one you have defined.  I would suggest that you raise an error.  Your function doesn't return anything, so it needs something else to tell the caller that he gave the wrong arguments to your function.

I am happy to see that you have an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.  That is something that is left out by many.

Comment: Thanks for spending your valuable time to review my code. I took note of all your points and changed it. But when I  changed the coordinate creation line in the start_game_animation function to not include list function, I get an error that I couldn't use the random.shuffle() function. So How could I shuffle a generator?

Comment: @Boopesh: I forgot about that part.  It is probably better just to stick with the list.  Since you know how many items the generator will produce, however, you could use `coordinates = sample(coordinates, BOARD_HEIGHT * BOARD_WIDTH)`